# R purrr accumulate over nested tibbles

Tags: r, purrr, accumulate

I need to accumulate a value over nested tibbles.

Here is my simplified example:

```
tab <- data.frame(A = c("A","B","A","B"),
                  ID = c(1,1,2,2),
                  V1 = c(20,40,25,30),
                  V2 = c(0.2,0.8,0.3,0.7)
                  ) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    nest()
```

In my solution, the accumulate function use as initial value always 1000 instead of the accumulated "1000".

```
tab %>%
    mutate(
        G_i = purrr::accumulate(data,
                                function(G_i,data){
                                    out <- data %>%
                                        group_by(A) %>%
                                        mutate(G_i = G_i+G_i*V2/V1)
                                    sum(out$G_i)
                                },
                                .init = 1000)%>%
            tail(-1)
    )

 A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID data               G_i
  <dbl> <list>           <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [2 × 3]> 2030 
2     2 <tibble [2 × 3]> 2035.
```

The desired output should deliver:

```
A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID data               G_i
  <dbl> <list>           <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [2 × 3]> 2030 
2     2 <tibble [2 × 3]> 4131.727
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your data is grouped so `accumulate()` is essentially being applied to each row separately. Do you need to `ungroup()` before doing your calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @MikkoMarttila, all you need need to do is `ungroup` prior to using `accumulate`.

```
library(tidyverse)

tab %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(
    G_i = purrr::accumulate(data,
                            function(G_i,data){
                              out <- data %>%
                                group_by(A) %>%
                                mutate(G_i = G_i+G_i*V2/V1)
                              sum(out$G_i)
                            },
                            .init = 1000)%>%
      tail(-1)
  )
```

Output

```
     ID data               G_i
  <dbl> <list>           <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [2 × 3]> 2030.000 
2     2 <tibble [2 × 3]> 4131.727
```